# unable to send multipart/form-data to nodejs server

Tags: reactjs, axios

I am trying to send multipart/formdata in my react app. Everytime I hit the POST api using axios, the formdata is always empty.I tried converting to JSON.stringify and key-value method, but nothing seems to work. I do have my headers set as `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`

```
postList = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();


    var postParams;
    if(this.state.message && this.state.parent){

      postParams = {
        message: this.state.message,
        chat_m_id: this.state.parent,
        depth: (1).toString(),
        msg_icon: this.state.msg_icon.name
      }
    }
    else{    
      postParams = {
        message: this.state.message,
        chat_m_id: (0).toString(),
        depth: (0).toString(),
        msg_icon: this.state.msg_icon.name
      }
    }
    console.log(postParams);
    let bodyFormData = new FormData();

    //approach-one
      bodyFormData.append('data',postParams);

    //approach-one
      // bodyFormData.append('data',JSON.stringify(postParams));

    //approach-three
      // for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(postParams)) {
      //     bodyFormData.append(`'${key}'`, JSON.stringify(`${value}`));
      // }

console.log(bodyFormData) //this is always empty


    axios.post(GlobalVar.BASE_URL+'api/msgtemplate/create', bodyFormData, {headers: GlobalVar.headersFormData})
    .then(res => {
      console.log(res)
      this.props.history.push('/messages')
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err.res));

  }
```

I have spent hours on this, please help to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of sending files with axios:

In your case, I have debugged your code here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-ypnbv?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

```
state = { selectedFile: null }
//handler for file change event
fileChangedHandler = event => {
  this.setState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] })
}

  uploadHandler = () => {
    const formData = new FormData()
    formData.append(
      'myFile',
      this.state.selectedFile,
      this.state.selectedFile.name
    )
    axios.post('my-domain.com/file-upload', formData)
  }
```

Comment: I am following the similar approach. If you can help debug my code?

Comment: Here is the dummy https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-nwfq3?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: @bubble-cord u cant upload files and firstname and lastname at same backend api, files must be different api, then send first last names in different api, I have edited codesandbox to upload file, if u want to upload name, make another button which does that